# C# WPF нарисовать сетку сверху Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть Canvas с ImageBrush, нужно показать сетку координат сверху него с возможностю масштабирования.

Вот пример сетки в дизайнере Visual Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел пример с DrawingBrush

```
  <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="-10,-10,40,40" 
                                 ViewportUnits="Absolute">
      <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
         <GeometryDrawing>                 
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
               <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
               <Pen Brush="Gray" Thickness="1"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
         </GeometryDrawing>
      </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
   </DrawingBrush>
```

но совместить с ImageBrush не получилось

Comment: Ничего не понятно, попробуйте переформулировать ваш вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 обновил

Comment: Отобразите прозрачный канвас поверх картинки и рисуйте на нем сетку :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По-быстрому склацал:

<sub>Controls/Lattice.cs</sub>

```cs
public class Lattice : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RodPenProperty;

    public Pen? RodPen
    {
        get => GetValue(RodPenProperty) as Pen;
        set => SetValue(RodPenProperty, value);
    }

    static Lattice()
    {
        RodPenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "RodPen",
            typeof(Pen),
            typeof(Lattice));
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext context)
    {
        const double maxCellSide = 50.0; // длина стороны 1-й клетки
        const int splitCnt = 2; // кол-во клеток, на которое будет производиться деление
        const double splitTreshold = 6.0; // порог расщепления (так просто не объяснить)

        if (!(Background is null)) context.DrawRectangle(Background, null!, new Rect(default, RenderSize));

        if (RodPen is null) return;

        var side = Math.Max(ActualWidth, ActualHeight);
        var cellSide = side / splitTreshold;

        for (; cellSide >= maxCellSide; cellSide /= splitCnt) { }

        var horRodCnt = (int)(ActualWidth / cellSide) + 1;
        var verRodCnt = (int)(ActualHeight / cellSide) + 1;

        for (var i = 1; i < horRodCnt; i++)
        {
            var offsetX = i * cellSide;

            context.DrawLine(RodPen, new Point(offsetX, 0), new Point(offsetX, ActualHeight));
        }
        for (var i = 1; i < verRodCnt; i++)
        {
            var offsetY = i * cellSide;

            context.DrawLine(RodPen, new Point(0, offsetY), new Point(ActualWidth, offsetY));
        }
    }
}
```

*Примечание: константы **заменить** на свойства зависимостей.*

<sub>MainWindow.xaml</sub>

```
<Window x:Class="RootNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RootNamespace"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:RootNamespace.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ctrl:Lattice>
            <ctrl:Lattice.RodPen>
                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Gray"/>
            </ctrl:Lattice.RodPen>
        </ctrl:Lattice>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Меняйте размер окна: получаете иллюзию бесконечной сетки. Маштабирование – это и есть изменение размера (конечно, относительное).

---

Я думал, как реализовать это с помощью `ImageBrush`, но так и не придумал. Думаю, тут стоит использовать `VisualBrush`.